# Unable to start TensorFlow within Docker, on Windows

Tags: docker, tensorflow

Hope I didn't miss anything.
I've installed docker on my win 7 using this guide:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/
I opened a new terminal and entered the following command:

```
docker run -it b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow
```

All donwloaded and extracted and then I get the following massages:

```
[I 16:09:55.069 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret 
[W 16:09:55.122 NotebookApp] WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP
 addresses and not using encryption. This is not recommended. 
[W 16:09:55.122 NotebookApp] WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP
 addresses and not using authentication. This is highly insecure and not recommended.
[I 16:09:55.134 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /notebooks 
[I 16:09:55.134 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 16:09:55.134 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://[all ip addresses on your system]:8888/ 
[I 16:09:55.134 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all
 kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

And then it just gets stuck like this, there's no command line and I can't enter anything... what am I missing?

Comment: It looks fine. Your terminal is 'connected' to the container. You can use the `-d` switch to daemonize: `docker run -d -it b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow`

Comment: Tried, altough it's not getting stuck after doing so, when opening python and trying to write    'import tensorflow as tf' 
I get "No module named tensorflow" error...

Comment: That seems to be unrelated to docker, I'm sorry I don't know much about python.

Comment: The command `docker run -d -it b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow` does not make sense! Using `-d` to run the container in background mode while using `-it` to run it interactively with a tty? What do you expect from it? Can you provide a Dockerfile? Try to run: `docker run -it --net=host b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow`, or better, `docker run -it --p 8888:8888 b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow` and then, with a browser, go to `http://host-ip:8888` (do not use localhost, unless you use `--net=host`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, So i found a sort of an answer,
There are two ways to solve it:
1) Install tensorflow with source code instead, this seems to solve the problem.
This is done by writing:
`docker run -it b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel`
2) Or, if you use the regular install, before installing check
the default VM IP with:

```
docker-machine ip default
```

And then, after installtion go in the brwoser to http://(default_ip):8888/

Comment: Thank you , that was awesome! I don't know why the binary release of tensorflow just hangs and doesn't bring you back to the prompt but the development version sure does.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and was able to get it working by following these steps:

```
$ docker-machine ip default
```

Remember this `DOCKER_IP` value (copy to clipboard) in my case

```
192.168.99.100
```

Now start your TensorFlow docker container (with port forwarding):

```
$ docker run -it -p 8888:8888 gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow
```

Now open the web browser:

```
$ open http://localhost:8888
```

You should now see your browser with the jupyter home page

I'm working on more notes on [Getting started wtih TensorFlow here](https://github.com/stujo/tensorflow-what-is-it) some of that is OSX specific though

Update: I have a better understanding now so I'm updating the answer - A docker image makes certain ports available (EXPORTable) for mapping, but by default does not map them to the host machines ports when the container is run.

We can map them to the host by using the -p option. We specify which host port (if any) the already EXPORTed port should be mapped to on the host.

```
$ docker run -p $HOSTPORT:$CONTAINERPORT someimage
```

Comment: Thanks, you can see that this is option 2 that I've suggseted, but your explanation is more detailed.

Comment: I did this, so now I have the browser open. How can I actually code in tensorflow here?

Comment: Try this: On your docker container open the 1_hello_tensorflow.ipynb Notebook, for me:
http://192.168.99.100:8888/notebooks/1_hello_tensorflow.ipynb

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The notebook doesn't load. Just "refused to connect"

Comment: Try accessing open http://localhost:8888 after using the -p option as described above